# SVG raw not showing text in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, svg, icons

I have a svg file that includes a text that will be modified in my flutter app. The problem is: in my app the svg icon displays good but the text inside the icon doesn't (If I open the icon in the browser the text displays ok).

I'm using a map sdk that needs the svg icon as Uint8List to draw it, so I need the svg raw code units to draw the icon ( I must not change it).

I will add the code example to clarify.

```
 rawSvg = await rootBundle.loadString(SVG_ICON_ASSET); 
 rawSvg = rawSvg.replaceAll('##', eventsCount.toString());
    
return MapImage.withImageDataImageFormatWidthAndHeight(
        Uint8List.fromList(rawSvg.codeUnits),
        ImageFormat.svg,
        200,
        200);
```

Comment: Check that `eventsCount.toString()` is behaving as expected ... maybe even remove that line temporarily to check that `##` is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you convert the text to path. You can check out by opening the Inkscape, For me Inkscape is sufficient so I don't use Adobe Illustrator and nor do I know anything about it. But in Inkscape you can check it by Selecting the text object only and go to **Object** **-** and then select **Objects** from the drop down menu , it will show a new Window ( I'm using latest version so if you're using older the interface can be different).

[image: Inkscape]

Here you will your text Object. If it has paths like I have already converted it to paths then you probably should check path colors in Android Studio, because Android Studio sometimes during convertion to vector graphics changes the path colors. If the text is not in path you can convert it like below.

[image]

I have created another text Object to explain don't get confused. After converting it to path every **Character** will get converted to a path.

This all happens because Android Studio can't convert Objects to path and don't even shows the error sometimes.